# One-way [Parameter] binding programatically

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to set defaults for parameters on a third-party component. Say I have this:

myBasePage.cs:

```cs
public class MyBasePage : ComponentBase
{
  public IEnumerable MyData { get; set; }
}
```

myPage.razor:

```cs
@inherits MyBasePage
<ThirdPartyComponent Data="@MyData" />
```

Since `Data` on `ThirdPartyComponent` is a `[Parameter]` with a `DataHasChanged()` virtual method, by rendering the blazor component like that, I'll get one-way binding, and if I change `MyData` on my page, programmatically, the component will update. *This will work fine.*

Now, say I can't modify `ThirdPartyComponent`, but I want to make some defaults in it based on my base page... like so:

myPage.razor:

```cs
@inherits MyBasePage
<MyDerivedComponent PageComponent="@this" />
```

myDerivedComponent.cs:

```cs
public class MyDerivedComponent : ThirdPartyComponent 
{
   [Parameter] public MyBasePage PageComponent { get; set; }
   public override void OnInitialized()
   {
      /* Set other parameter defaults */
      this.OtherParameter = 10;

      /* Bind to Data, as if I was passing it as a parameter in the Razor template */
      this.Data = PageComponent.MyData;
   }
}
```

This line:

```cs
this.Data = PageComponent.MyData;
```

Doesn't create a binding at all (and if I modify `MyData`, the blazor component doesn't get updated). Is there any way to programmatically create it?

**Note**: the real `ThirdPartyComponent` includes not only tons of parameters but also templates, etc. For many reasons, I'd like `MyDerivedComponent` to be of a derived type, and not a "parent component" with a child of `ThirdPartyComponent`, if that's possible at all).

Comment: I don't think `Data="@MyData"` will make the page re-render whenever `MyData` changes. Do you change its value as a response to some events?

Comment: @PharazFadaei it doesn't automatically, but it does if you do a  `StateHasChanged` or it's an `EventCallback`. If I set it programatically (not on the razor component template), it does neither.

Comment: @PharazFadaei that is, if I do `<MyDerivedComponent Data="@this.Data">`, it works as expected... if I set it via code (`<MyDerivedComponent PageComponent="@this">`, then `this.Data = PageComponent.Data;`), it doesn't

Comment: Do you mean if you only do `Data="@this.Data"` and then change the value of `this.Data` the component will automatically re-render?

Comment: @PharazFadaei if I issue a `StateHasChanged()` after changing the value (or `this.Data` changes on a `EventCallback<>`), yes... that's the basis of one-way binding in Blazor

Comment: Rather than deriving from `ThirdPartyComponent`, how about creating a container component that accepts the `Data` parameter and then forwards the parameter to `ThirdPartyComponent`? This intermediate container component can then have the markup to render `<ThirdPartyComponent Data="DataToBeForwarded" \>` and you can indirectly use `ThirdPartyComponent` via this intermediate component.

Comment: @AmalK yep, that was the obvious way to go, but if you read the note in the bottom of the question, that component in particular has templates (`RenderFragments`), and tons of parameters which I want to be able to set independently. It's doable, but a ton of work (plus I'd have to update it if anything changes on the third party component on an update). I was looking for an easiest way if there was.... but seems there isn't.

Comment: The other obvious way is having a `DataHasChanged()` event on the base page model and bind to that (which is probably what I'll ultimately do)... but since there is already a binding mechanism, I wanted to know if I could access it somehow... glancing at the sources of Blazor, it seems there isn't... it's inbuilt on the implementation of `RenderTreeBuilder` and all of it is internal, and based on the key number of each instruction in the Blazor compiler, so I think I'm out of luck here

Comment: I saw someone suggested to do `this.Data = PageComponent.Data;` inside the `OnParametersSet`, I think it is going to work. Did you try it? Was there a problem?

Comment: @PharazFadaei since `Data` is not bound, you `OnParameterSet` just doesn't fire when you change `PageComponent.Data`... only when you change `PageComponent` (which is what is bound now). I tested it just in case, and it didn't work either

Comment: Assuming you call `StateHasChanged` on `MyBasePage` whenever the value of `Data` changes, the `MyBasePage` component will rerender accordingly. `MyDerivedComponent` is a child of `MyBasePage` and has a complex-typed parameter (`PageComponent`) so its `OnParametersSet` will be called based on [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-5.0#after-parameters-are-set-onparameterssetasync).

Comment: @PharazFadaei actually it seems it does... I must have been doing something else wrong.

Comment: @HenkHolterman if you undelete your answer I'll accept it, because it does work :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
public class MyDerivedComponent : ThirdPartyComponent 
{
   [Parameter] public MyBasePage PageComponent { get; set; }
   public override void OnInitialized()
   {
      /* Set other parameter defaults */
      this.OtherParameter = 10;


      //this.Data = PageComponent.MyData;
   }
}

 protected override void OnParametersSet()   
 {
    Data = Data ?? PageComponent?.MyData ;  // determine priority
    base.OnParametersSet();
 }
```

`OnParametersSet()` notifies the Component that it has new Parameters. The most-derived class can intervene here.

But there is no easy solution for wwhen `this.MyData` changes, that's out of sight for Blazor.

Comment: That doesn't work when `PageComponent.Data` changes, no parameters are changed on the component because there's no binding subscription to `Data` at all, so it just doesn't call `OnParameterSet`, unless I change the whole `PageComponent`.

Comment: Looking at the sources of Blazor, it seems the `RenderTreeBuilder` "subscribes" to the bound attributes with the key number when they are bound (at render time), so it looks for changes on state change. But all of that is internal (and implementation dependant), plus I don't have access to the compiled render tree, so I think I'm out of luck here.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Maybe I misread "Doesn't create a binding at all".

Comment: But PageComponent is a complex type, it should assume a change, no?

Answer (score 1):

*Is there any way to programmatically create it?*  Of course, but that doesn't mean that you should.

*Parameters* should not be set or manipulated within the component code.  Parameters are set externally whenever `SetParametersAsync` is called by the `Renderer`.  If you change them internally you create two versions of the truth.